# K3s high available cluster on cloud

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, nginx-ingress, k3s

I am trying to create a cluster using k3s with n number of nodes, where all the nodes are servers only, and there are no agent/worker nodes. By default, a k3s server works as an agent. And I am trying to add a load balancer that can work for both API-Server and client side. I mean it can serve the 443 port (webserver) as well. I need a hybrid solution for the load balancer as I want to support on-prem and cloud both.

I was going through metalLB as it doesn't support cloud. [Here](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/clouds/) it is mentioned that metalLb is not compatible with cloud providers. I am confused a bit about the load balancer where to add it?

Below I am adding an image of an architecture I want to build, not sure where the load balancer should I keep?

[image: A Simple Architecture]

Please someone guide me in a right direction so I can complete the flow.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From your use case, it seems what you need is just a simple NGINX reverse proxy as an load balancer.

Before explaining further, you must understand that the *ingress* is not something outside of the k8s node, it is actually an abstract layer in the k8s clusters, which allows traffic from outside of the cluster to go to certain exposed *services*.

Instead of placing an "ingress" behind the k8s nodes, just host an nginx reverse proxy machine, which listen to `443` and `6443`, and forward the requests to the k3s nodes. It provides you Load Balancing while serving both Web access and admin access.

For example, you should have two configs:

```
upstream nodes {
    server 192.168.1.XXXX:80;
    server 192.168.1.YYYY:80;
    server 192.168.1.ZZZZ:80;
    server 192.168.1.QQQQ:80;
} 

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name someservice.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_set_header Connection       $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://nodes;
  }
}
```

and another for the 6443 admin access

```
stream {
    upstream kubernetes {
        server 192.168.1.XXXX:6443;
        server 192.168.1.YYYY:6443;
        server 192.168.1.ZZZZ:6443;
    }
    server {
        listen 6443; # Forward all 6443 traffic to the kubernetes upstream
        proxy_pass kubernetes;
    }
}
```